# Rails instance method class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shopping-cart, instance-methods

I want to make a shopping cart and I've create a new class in rails that calls ShoppingCart. In the class I have instance method called total_qualtity. 
I call this class in View and try to call instance method but I got

*"NoMethodError in Default#index"* and *"undefined method `total_quantity' for "#":String"* . Please help me to fix it.

this is my ShoppingCart.rb

```
class ShoppingCart
attr_accessor :items
def initialize items = Hash.new
    @items = items
end

def total_quantity
    total = 0
    @items.each do |key, value| 
        total += value.to_i
    end
    return total
end
```

and this is my DefaultView.html.erb

```
<% @cart = session[:cart] || ShoppingCart.new
  session[:cart] = @cart
  puts session[:cart].total_quantity  --> This is place i got error
%>
<div id="header" class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><%= image_tag 'logo.png'%></a>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You're calling it on a string, not a cart.

Comment: could you explain it? i don't understand why it contain a string

Comment: Something else puts something into session, and it's a string.

Comment: You can cannot store an object in session. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978704/object-stored-in-rails-session-becomes-a-string

Comment: @DaveNewton, I never assign any kind of text or string into the session

Comment: It change to string when I refresh the page and become Error. In the first load, it doesn't appear an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the cart_id in session not complete object and retrieve object of ShoppingCart from that id.
Do this in controller

```
Eg: session[:cart_id] 
@cart  = ShoppingCart.find(session[:cart_id])
```

and pass @cart object to the view and use like that

```
@cart.total_quantity
```

Comment: My ShoppingCart is a class with No ActiveRecord::Base. So i can't use find  method.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the object as a `String` to the `session[:cart_id]`.